# Express async get request, calling async function hanging

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

Hello I'm new to express...

I have an express file like:

```
const app = express();
const getPerson = require("./db/queries/PersonQuery");

app.get('/getCitizen/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const person = await getPerson.getCitizenById(`${req.params.id}`);
        console.log(person);
        res.send(person);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I have the function we are calling looks like this:

```
const getCitizenById = async (id) => {
    try {
        const citizen = await CitizenSchema.find({
            citizenID : id
        });

        const cit1 = citizen[0];
        console.log(cit1);

        return cit1;

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

module.exports = { getCitizenById };
```

When I call: `http://localhost:3000/getCitizen/123`
On postman, my request just hangs and returns nothing, and print nothing except connecting to the database.

Can any1 help me out?

Thanks a lot

EDIT:

Citizen Schema:

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const citizenSchema = new Schema({
    citizenID : String,
    forenames : String,
    surname : String,
    homeAddress : String,
    dateOfBirth : String,
    placeOfBirth : String,
    sex : String
}, 
    { 
        collection : 'citizen10k'
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('citizen10k', citizenSchema);
```

Comment: Is there any other middleware before this route?

Comment: @AbdurrahimAhmadov I have no middleware

Comment: Can you share the Citizen model and schema ?

Comment: @ZahidÇakıcı Hello, see edit thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I rewrote my code, I embedded the getCitizenId function into a new function that was ran as a middleware and I included next().

Now works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).